# Abp.io Identity user restore deleted user

Tags: .net, abp

i want to restore user record after soft delete.

i want use idatafilter in identityuser application service.
but i don't have development permission of `volo.abp.identity.identityUser` Application Service.

how i get and update soft deleted users

**UPDATE:** https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Customizing-Application-Modules-Overriding-Services

this article contains solution of this problem.

Comment: You can replace the corresponding Application Service for this. Please check the docs. https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Customizing-Application-Modules-Overriding-Services

Comment: thank you for your comment, this article can resolve my problem.